# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME - Do not lose selection when cursor leave textfield and holding mouse down

Tags: 18.04, mouse, gnome-shell

Is it possible setup GNOME to not lose or do not invert selection when cursor leave textfield and continue moving in right direction with holding mouse click? (KDE, MS Windows way: selection follow cursor even if them left the field). It is not always convenient and it is not always possible to move mouse cursor exactly along the text field, especially over long distances.

Examples with Firefox address bar (but you can see same behavior on any another textfield):

1. Start moving

   [image]
2. Hand has flinched and I lose selection

   [image]
3. **Best practice** (do not need to be a mouse sniper - KDE, MS Windows way):

   [image]

In 3rd case is no need return cursor to text field and spend time cursor aiming.

Comment: Does it really lose selection? I think it doesn't, but also doesn't show any visual indication. If you bring the cursor back again after leaving the text-field you'll see it selects the right part of text.

Comment: @pomsky, Added additional 3rd case with best selection behavior when selection follow mouse on any vertical displacement of mouse cursor. This is immediately evident when you switch from windows to gnome. Returning cursor to text field is an additional waste of time.

Comment: Well, GNOME is not a clone of Windows after all.

Comment: Yeah, but we must wish get the best, that reduces the time of work with the interface, not complicate it. BTW MacOS, KDE (Krusader) work like in 3rd case too. It is always more difficult to get into bottlenecks with the cursor than just move it!

Comment: I don't completely understand concern tbh. After all, there should be a *starting point* (at the right) and an *ending point* (at the left) of the intended selection. The rule is pretty simple to me: "click-&-hold at the starting point, then take the cursor to the ending point *following any path* and release". I understand you rather want to a 'vertical line' as the ending bound instead of a point.